# How do I Disable the Code Cache for PHP 5 (FPM) with Nginx?

Tags: caching, nginx, php

When I save changes to a PHP file and then reload, it continues to execute the old version of the script for a minute or so regardless of how many refreshes I do. After 1 minute (or so) it executes the current version.

How do I disable this behaviour so changes occur immediately?

Setup is PHP-FPM with Nginx.

Comment: nginx does not cache by default. linux has no file cache by default. did you set up your server?

Comment: Yes, I setup the server. I believe the new version of PHP has built-in opcode caching though.

Comment: comment out the opcache extension (opcache.so) in your ini

Comment: No instance of `opcache.so` was found in `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`

Comment: Try opcache.enable=Off - but from waht I've read opcache isn't enabled by default either and must be explicitly enabled when doing ./configure

Comment: I have the same problem but with Apache (mod_fastcgi) and PHP-FPM. Neither OpCache or APC are installed. Also have the same issue with Apache and mod_fcgi. And, no, it's not a browser cache issue. Force-refreshign the page gives me updated static files, but stale php code.

Answer (score 7):

My solution was in the Zend OPCache configuration rather than APC.

I installed the vanilla version of WNMP (PHP 5.5.11) on my Windows 8.1 box and discovered in my `php.ini` file's `[opcache]` section that the Zend OPCache was enabled and only checking file changes once every 60 seconds (`opcache.revalidate_freq=60`). Look for that config directive and set it to `0` to force the OPCache to check php files on each request.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (localhost dev server, Nginx 1.10.0, PHP 7.0.13, no OPCache, no APC), setting **realpath_cache_ttl** to **0** and then restarting the PHP-FPM service did a trick. But one has to be careful changing this value on production server.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My was related to APC extension caching.
You can use the PHP function apc_clear_cache.

Answer (score 0):

using APC? check your APC section in php.ini

make sure apc.stat=1

http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.stat