# Docker web server (nginx + php5.6) not update when code change

Tags: php, laravel, macos, docker

I pull an images from docker hub and run a container from that image by command:

```
docker run -d -p 8081:80 -v /Users/nguyenphong/Documents/tiki/fulfillment:/src --name fulfillment tala/nginx-php
```

docker container run good and web service work well, but when i started to code, i changed some code in my local dir, i see the code change in container folder but when i reload the web application, "nothing change".

When i run :

```
docker restart fulfillment
```

code applied.

So what i need to do to live reload the code change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not sound like a docker issue. PHP and nginx have been known to cache files for a couple of minutes even if there are changes. You might have to change some configuration in php.ini.

Take a look at this answer, it might help you:
[How do I Disable the Code Cache for PHP 5 (FPM) with Nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364731/how-do-i-disable-the-code-cache-for-php-5-fpm-with-nginx)

Comment: Thank you so much, i disable turn off opcache in php.ini and it work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to delete the Docker instance to make sure that it is cache issue; Try deleting the Docker instance by running 'docker rm -f fulfillment' and then rerun the 'docker run ....' command to make sure it is working fine without any issue.

Comment: Thank you so much, i try turn off opcache in php.ini and it work fine.

Comment: Could you mark above answer as a solution? The turning off of opcache was your solution. Also edit your own question and post the solution.
Last: PHP 5.6 will almost be depreceated...